# equivalent for enable and disable validate and novalidate in db2

Tags: db2

I want to enable constraint but don't validate existing record. only validate future record in db2.

This should be apply for check constraint.

```
alter table table_name add check (column_name <> '')
```

Answer (score 0):

DB2 hast the `ENFORCED` and `NOT ENFORCED` options for check constraints. The syntax for constraints is part of the [CREATE TABLE](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000927.html) and [ALTER TABLE](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000888.html) statements. A sub-option is to either set `TRUSTED` or `NOT TRUSTED` depending on the quality of your data.

Something like the following should work:

```
alter table mytable add check (column1>myvalue) not enforced trusted
```

Comment: DB2 sql error : sqlcode =-104,sqlstate=42602,sqlerrmc=trusted;<>' ')not enforced;END-OF-STATEMENT,DRIVER=3.59.81

Comment: You have not posted what you tried and the error is a syntax error.

Comment: alter table table_name add check (column_name <> '')  not enforced trusted    DB2 sql error : sqlcode =-104,sqlstate=42602,sqlerrmc=trusted;<>' ')not enforced;END-OF-STATEMENT,DRIVER=3.59.81

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this

```
ALTER TABLE YOURLIB.YOURTABLE DROP CONSTRAINT YOURLIB.YOURCONSTRAINTNAME1;

ALTER TABLE YOURLIB.YOURTABLE ADD CONSTRAINT YOURLIB.YOURCONSTRAINTNAME1 CHECK (YOUCOLUMNNAME<>'') NOT ENFORCED TRUSTED;
```

Comment: DB2 sql error : sqlcode =-104,sqlstate=42602,sqlerrmc=trusted;<>' ')not enforced;END-OF-STATEMENT,DRIVER=3.59.81